# How to parse excel contents from excel document using php

Tags: php

I have an excel document with many columns.I want to parse that data.Please help in php.Provide simple means to guide

Thanks

Comment: its save as csv or xls ?

Comment: Excel is a proprietary binary format. Good luck. A cell could have a video in it. A video! Or an entire C memory structure. It's ridiculous.

Comment: Converting the excel file into CSV will help you

Answer (score 3):

look at this class

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

you can find an example of read [here](http://bayu.freelancer.web.id/2010/07/16/phpexcel-advanced-read-write-excel-made-simple/)

Answer (score 1):

if it saves as CSV this is how to read it:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used this in one of my projects...works like a charm :P 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/